# How to automatically update a .net app on startup when released to a network location

Tags: c#, .net, oneclick

Current setup:
.Net application
VSTS release definitions

What would be the best way have an application automatically or manually update on or before application startup?

Given:
-A network drive containing the last 5 releases .../bin/release/{stuff including the .exe}

The currently considered approach is OneClick - is this an appropriate one?

*please comment below if you need more details*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) - it is much like OneClick but much easier to get working and is OSS. Once included in your app the updates are pretty seamless and it even does delta updates for you.

It can be installed using Nuget - see the [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/docs/getting-started/0-overview.md)

Comment: Thanks, will have a look

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for